# Why is Chrome's service worker *cache* directory in ~/.config instead of ~/.cache?

Tags: google-chrome, cache

One of the largest folders in terms of disk usage after just using my new install for one day is `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Service Worker/CacheStorage`. I'm using Chrome v101 (current stable) on Linux.

I expected cache files to go to `~/.cache` which Google Chrome is also using already (`~/.cache/google-chrome`) for other caching purposes. I like to have a simple exclude for running my backups efficiently. I'm wondering why Chrome is the only app with half of its *cache* files going to the *config* folder.

I'm inclined to set up a separate folder in `~/.cache` and put a symbolic link in place.

But it strikes me... is there a reason why this `Service Worker/CacheStorage` has to go in `~/.config`? Sounds rather odd to me.

<sup>Generally speaking I don't care about a gigabyte more or less of data, but this adds up significantly in my frequent incremental backups. And no this question is not about how to remove this large cache folder, but more about the WHY.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Google designed the app without support of [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) because they support Windows ))